# Как реализовать срабатывание кнопки при нажатии Enter в поле ввода?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function enterNum() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" id="txt">
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="enterNum()">Перевірит</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function enterNum() {
  console.log("test");
}

function checkForEnter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    document.querySelector(".block .button").click();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" id="txt" onkeydown="checkForEnter(event)">
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="enterNum()">Перевірит</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!) Сработало. Гуглил, но непонятно новичку

Comment: @JessicaBulldog Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ спустя 3 минуты
3 минуты еще жду)